# Merge error when deploying Laravel application

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Hi I just got this error when I deployed my Laravel app to staging:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_PARSE) 
syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL)
```

Seems to be a merge conflict in the package, any ideas?

```
Open: /var/www/ares/releases/20141103102236/vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/Route.php
        $this->path = $data['path'];
        $this->host = $data['host'];
        $this->defaults = $data['defaults'];
        $this->requirements = $data['requirements'];
        $this->options = $data['options'];
        $this->schemes = $data['schemes'];
        $this->methods = $data['methods'];
<<<<<<< HEAD
        $this->condition = $data['condition'];
=======
```

Comment: Well, manually fix the merge conflict. Then it should be okay.

Comment: You should not be commit the Vendor folder to your Git. You should be running `composer install` on your server instead

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/master/Route.php

Comment: In master 7 hours ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a temporary bug in the Symphony Routing file.

A recent commit today seems to have included the Git conflict into the file itself - seen here:

```
       $this->schemes = $data['schemes'];
        $this->methods = $data['methods'];
<<<<<<< HEAD
        $this->condition = $data['condition'];
=======
        if (isset($data['compiled'])) {
            $this->compiled = $data['compiled'];
        }
>>>>>>> 2.3
    }
```

Simply change it to this:

vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/Route.php

```
       $this->schemes = $data['schemes'];
       $this->methods = $data['methods'];
       $this->condition = $data['condition'];
       if (isset($data['compiled'])) {
           $this->compiled = $data['compiled'];
       }
    }
```

There is also a Git pull to fix the issue here: https://github.com/symfony/Routing/pull/3

Edit: This has now been fixed: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/12382